# what is the best strategy to encrypt only some values under appSettings in webconfig file using aspnet_regiis

Tags: c#, encryption, web-config, appsettings, aspnet-regiis.exe

I am trying to encrypt only some values under the appSettings in webconfig file using aspnet_regiis, What is the best strategy  for doing this ?

Comment: `aspnet_regiis` is a tool to register the .Net framework with IIS (basically make the two work together).  Personally, I just use the `ProtectedData`class ([Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx